# 2:3 aspect ratio button grid with rowspan

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I've been struggling with this for quite a while;
Im trying to do a list of parking spots, in such a way that there's two columns,
The left one is vertical spots, with an aspect ratio of 1:2, the right one is horizontal spots, 2:1 aspect ratio.

I'm trying to achieve this using Ionic's grids, and this is the closest I've gotten, but still not quite there:

[image: What I'm getting]
Notice the empty space below spot #18

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

Maybe there's an easier way to have a responsive layout that will maintain the aspect ratios?

**layout.html**

```
<ion-item>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
            <div class="col no-padding">
                <button class="button spot-tall">18</button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-66 no-padding">
            <div>
                <button class="button spot-wide">12</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="button spot-wide">11</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

**style.css**

```
.spot-tall {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%
}

.spot-wide {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 12.5%;
  padding-bottom: 12.5%
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your css classes here,It worked for me. Please check it

```
.spot-tall {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 70%
}

.spot-wide {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 12.5%;
  padding-bottom: 14.6%
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```